# Attaching more than 1 parent (Post) to a media file

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, media-library, media-settings

Im trying to build a Digital Album website for my family old pictures and albums. 
**I crated a custom post type via Pods** called "Family Members" and crated something like 30 Posts / Pages with the family members full names.

Now..
Im trying to upload a new image to my media library and can attach only **one** Page / Post (In my case it's a **family member**)to each media file (Image)

I want to attach more than 1 post (More than 1 Family Member) to each image that i uploaded.
so for example if i'll upload a picture of 2 people toghter i can attach the specific image to both of them.
Wordpress is limited me to 1 only.

how can i change it to multiple selection?

Thank you very much guys!
Maor.
[image]

Comment: If you're trying to modify the Pods UI then you will need to ask Pods support or Pods communities. 3rd party plugins and themes are offtopic here

Comment: Actully it's not what im trying to do. nothing with Pods. Pods just helped me to crate a custom post type but my question is about the default WordPress Core and how can i change something in there. (Change one selection limited to multiple selections)

Comment: The UI in your question is not a WordPress UI but a Pods UI, there is no selection UI like that in WordPress. The only way to set the parent of an attachment in standard WP is to go to the parent post and upload it there. The only way to change it without modifying the database itself is to delete the attachment and reupload it to a different post

Answer (score 0):

Posts/attachments can only have a single parent post, this is because the posts parent is a single column value in the posts table. This cannot be changed without making major modifications to WordPress core itself, and would introduce other unforeseen problems due to ambiguity.

Instead, if you want to group things by family member, you should use a taxonomy named `family_member` or something to that effect. Taxonomies are how you're meant to organise and group content.

How you would integrate that into the Pods selection UI in your question however, is a subject beyond the scope of this stack, you need to ask in Pods communities or Pods support